# How can I determine statistical significance in seed length and width measurements?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, statistics, biostatistics, seeds

I am researching seed size variation in cereals. I used ImageJ to measure the seeds and generated arbitrary values. Later I converted the measurements to micrometers. I took length and width measurements of 151 unique accessions of single cereal species. I measured ten seeds per accession and generated a mean. I have summarized the mean values by length and width of the ten smallest, medium, and largest seeds. I have calculated SD and SE. In GraphPad, I have grouped these into three data tables and summarized them into one summary figure. I would like to determine if there is any significant difference between the different accessions.

I am unsure of how to best conduct this analysis. I am looking for any suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: If this question is more about statistics (which I strongly suspect), it would probably be a good idea to migrate it over to statics.stackexchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I will repost in stats.stackexchange. Thanks.